# Is it OK to continue reading from stream after failure?

Tags: c++, istream, extraction-operator

I am using the following loop to read numbers from two files until both are exhausted:

```
int a, b;
while (file1 >> a, file2 >> b, file1 || file2) {
    if (file1 && file2) ... // use of both a and b
    if (file1) ... // use of a
    if (file2) ... // use of b
}
```

My program works. But is it guaranteed to work by the standard? That is, am I permitted to continue reading from a failed stream or an implementation can choose to throw an exception?

Comment: first you have to [clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) stream error flags.

Comment: Also your loops stops running in case of errors.

Comment: If you're asking whether you can continuously perform failed reads on a istream reliably once the fail state is set without repercussion (besides the obvious: the failed reads perpetually after the initial failure), then yes, you can. If you were shooting for cryptic, btw, congratulations; you found it.

Comment: @MarekR It does not say there that, if I don't clear the error flags, I could get into trouble with my example. A source (preferably a quote from the standard) would be much appreciated.

Comment: @WhozCraig I would appreciate if you could reply with a source. Do you mean that my code is cryptic? Why so?

Comment: What kind of source did you have in mind? You're looking for a citation from a standard stating failures always fail ad infinitum? I suspect you could probably find it no slower than we could (unless you've already looked and that's why you're here?).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, without throwing an exception. I am here because I have looked in places like cppreference.com and could not find it stated explicitly (or explicitly enough for me to see it). The standard is too cryptic for me as of yet.

Comment: Ahh. Well, an exception will only be tossed if you've enable stream exceptions on you source, but I understand now regardless.

Comment: This question got me wondering about multiple comma operators in one line, and their evaluation order, and what eventually gets returned. And now my head hurts.

Comment: @PicaudVincent Both replies so far suggest that clearing the flags is unnecessary. If they are wrong IYO, I will appreciate your reply with a source.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sorry for the noise, I miss read your question. I will delete my comment which is not relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can attempt to input something from a stream as many times as you want. Even after an attempt to input something from that stream failed. All that will happen is that all attempts to input something after a failed attempt to input something will also fail.

Long answer: `operator >>` behaves as a formatted input function [[istream.formatted.arithmetic]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/istream.formatted.arithmetic). Formatted input functions construct a local sentry object and only perform input if converting that sentry object to `bool` results in the value `true` [[istream.formatted.reqmts]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/istream.formatted#reqmts). By default (if you did not override this behavior by supplying custom character traits to the stream), an object of type `std::sentry` will be used. An `std::sentry` that has been constructed for a stream will evaluate to `true` only if `good()` was `true` [[istream::sentry]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/istream::sentry). `good()` only returns true if neither failbit nor badbit nor eofbit are set [[iostate.flags]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/input.output#iostate.flags-7). If `operator >>(int&)` attempts to input (due to successful construction and check of the sentry) but fails to do so, it will set the failbit [[istream.formatted.arithmetic]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/istream.formatted.arithmetic#3). If the corresponding flag in the exception mask of the stream is set (it is not set by default), setting the failbit will result in an exception being thrown [[iostate.flags]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/input.output#iostate.flags-6) [[iostate.flags]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/input.output#iostate.flags-5). Otherwise, the stream will simply be in a failed state and construction of a sentry object will result in `false` the next time around until you call `clear()`…

I would consider rewriting this code, for example

```cpp
do
{
    if (int a; file1 >> a)
        ; // use a
    if (int b; file2 >> b)
        ; // use b
} while (file1 || file2);
```

Comment: I did not know you could declare a variable inside the condition of `if` like that, thanks! But what do you with my very first `if`, where I want to use both `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Once a stream is in a failed state (failbit), further reads will also fail, but this is what you wanted to happen. These reads will **not** throw an exception - the failbit will only generate an exception if this is explicitly enabled via the stream's [exceptions()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) method. According to [this source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/), the default is that these exceptions are not enabled:

> All streams have goodbit by default (they do not throw exceptions due to error state flags being set).

Comment: Section/paragraph number?

Comment: The source I pointed to is a website, it doesn't have sections or paragraph numbers. I did not read the standard itself, I assumed the people who wrote the secondary source I pointed to - did.